# When to use Vectored-Interrupt vs. Non-vectored Interrupt?

Tags: exception, assembly, arm, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Why would you choose Vectored Interrupt and non-vectored interrupt?

I know the differences between them but not sure when you would use one over the other/what devices use either one!

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the hardware supports vectored interrupts, there is no reason not to use them. This is more a question of implementation cost (vector tables and prioritisation logic) vs software cost (reading status registers and looking up the correct vector).

As hardware has become cheaper over time, it makes sense to have dedicated logic to provide the correct vector address - this improves interrupt latency for typical real world implementations to start processing 'actual handler code'.

Where hardware supports both, the non-vectored mode may be for legacy compatibility, or for the unusual case where only one interrupt is required (possibly saving one or two cycles of latency).